# Total variation of a distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

The wikipedia page for [Total Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_of_probability_measures) says that "The total variation of any probability measure is exactly one" (and is therefore not interesting).

I don't get why.

For example, if I take a discrete distribution with `p[0]=0.5, p[1]=0.1, p[2]=0.3, p[3]=0.1`, its total variation appears to be 0.4+0.2+0.2=0.8<1. If I add `p[x<0]=p[x>3]=0` for good measure, I get 0.5+0.4+0.2+0.2+0.1=1.4>1.

What am I getting wrong? Is a discrete probability distribution not a probability measurement?

Comment: I'm not a hardcore mathematician, so not an answer, just what I understood by the situation. Probability of all possible events has to sum to one (otherwise some possibilities have been missed). Total variation is what it says, the variation between all points. I'm not clear where your values in the sum come from. If it is the level value of an ordinal variable you calculate on, that is not probability.

Comment: I though that the values of variation to be summed are the absolute values of the difference in probability between points, this is how it looks like from the example on the wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the definition $\Delta = \sup_i \sum_j |\mu(E_j^i)|$ you get exactly one. In fact for your example, let's $E = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $E_i:=\{E^i_j\}$ a part of $E$. We have $$E_i \in \mathcal{P}[E]:= \{\{\},\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{0,1,2\},\{0,1,3\},\{1,2,3\},\{0,1,2,4\}\}$$

The set of $\sum_j |\mu(E_j^i)|$ is $\{0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 1 \} = \{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1 \}$

The supremum is then $1$.

And if you add $p[x<0]=p[x>3]=0$ the probability of these set equal to 0. Then the supremum is not different.

Comment: But why are these the values of $\sum_j |\mu(E_j^i)|$ ? More specifically, isn't $\mu(E_j^i)$ equal to the sum of $|(p(E_j)-p(E_j-1)|$ ? like in the example from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable

Comment: To put it another way - what is explicitly the value of $\mu$ over the partition {0,1,2,3}?

Comment: No no, here, your measure (function) is not continue. Then $\mu(\{0\}) = p(0) =0.5$ and $\mu(\{0,1,2\}) = \mu(\{0\})+\mu(\{1\})+\mu(\{2\}) = 0.5+0.1+0.3=0.8$

Comment: Okay, I understand that I don't really understand what the measure $\mu$ means, so I have to work on that.

Comment: Wait - but if I take some distribution with two overlapping peaks, the integral over absolute values of differential differences in function values will still not be 1 (only if I have a single peak)...

Comment: If the distribution is continue, the best partition of the set you will do is borelian which is the set of all intervall included in your set. Then $\mu$ of all set will also be a probability then less or equal to 1. The proprety will still hold